# Nested if statement in C - why doesn't it evaluate the last else if?

Tags: c, if-statement, control-flow

The following code does not execute the last `else if` statement when you assign to `choice` value `3`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    puts("Specify with a number what is that you want to do.");
    puts("1. Restore wallet from seed.");
    puts("2. Generate a view only wallet.");
    puts("3. Get guidance on the usage from within monero-wallet-cli.");

    unsigned char choice;
    choice = getchar(); 
 
    if ( choice == '1' ) {
        system("nice -19 ~/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0/monero-wallet-cli --testnet --restore-deterministic-wallet"); 
        exit(0);
    }
    else if ( choice == '2' ) {
        system("nice -19 ~/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0/monero-wallet-cli --testnet --generate-from-view-key wallet-view-only");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if ( choice == '3' ) {    
        puts("Specify with a number what is that you want to do.");
        puts("1. Get guidance in my addresses and UTXOs");
        puts("2. Pay");
        puts("3. Get guidance on mining.");
    
        unsigned char choicetwo = getchar();
        if ( choicetwo == '1' ) {      
            printf("Use \033address all\033 to get all your addresses that have any balance, or that you have generated at this session.");
            printf("Use \033balance\033 to get your balance");
            printf("Use \033show_transfers\033 to get ");
            printf("Use \033show_transfers\033 out to get ");
            printf("Use \033show_transfers in\033 to get your balance");
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

I get the following output When I enter `3`:

```
Specify with a number what is that you want to do.
1. Restore wallet from seed.
2. Generate a view only wallet.
3. Get guidance on the usage from within monero-wallet-cli.
3
Specify with a number what is that you want to do.
1. Get guidance in my addresses and UTXOs
2. Pay
3. Get guidance on mining.
```

I'm really blocked, something is missing and I have no clue why it does not proceed to take the input from the user for the second time.

Comment: Btw, do not assign the return value of `getchar()` to a `char` or `unsigned char` until you have first checked whether its value was `EOF`.

Comment: @Nate Is it because Ctrl-D pressed results in `-1` assigned as the return value of `getchar()` Nevertheless, I'm still able to quit when pressing `Ctrl-D`, despite the fact that the return value was declared as an unsigned char. Is declaring the variable as an int fixing it? Like so: `unsigned char choice;`? P.S. I chose to use `char` instead of `int` in order to save on memory. With the choice of `getchar()`  I wanted to avoid the issue of the buffer overflow related to `scanf()`.

Comment: the posted c ode does not cleanly compile!  *untitled.c:11:14: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘unsigned char’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   11 |     choice = getchar();
      |              ^~~~~~~
untitled.c:27:35: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘unsigned char’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   27 |         unsigned char choicetwo = getchar();
      |                                   ^~~~~~~*

Comment: @user3629249 It does with `gcc` on mine machine: x86_64. No warnings from `gcc`. What compiler have you used?

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska,  I'm using `gcc` with the options:  `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl-D will still work, but you'll be unable to tell the difference between that and the user having input character 255.  Probably not likely for this program, but if you're processing a file then character 255 is entirely possible to be there.  Trying to save memory with one variable is a bit silly, especially because this one is likely to be optimized into a register and use no memory at all.

Comment: If you needed to save a whole string, then sure, use an array of `unsigned char`.  But assign the return value of `getchar()` to an `int` first, check to see if it equals `EOF`, and if not then copy it into your array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you enter "3" for the first input, you're actually inputting two characters: the character `'3'` and a newline.  The first `getchar` function reads "3" from the input stream, and the second one reads the newline.

After accepting the first input, you'll want to call `getchar` in a loop until you read a newline to clear the input buffer.

```
choice = getchar();
while (getchar() != '\n');
```